# Customizing the layout of the *Bookmarks List* buffer?

Tags: buffers, bookmarks

What would be the best way to go about customizing the layout of the bookmarks *Bookmarks List* buffer?  I'd like to end up with a result similar to the Spacemacs equivalent buffer:

[image: Spacemacs bookmarks list buffer]

That is, the default header and column headings have been replaced with a single line header and 2-column indent. I also have bookmarks+ active which must be altering that buffer too.

Any advice much appreciated,

Thanks,

Stu

Answer (score 2):

You cannot easily do that. The [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) layout generally follows that of vanilla Emacs, but more information is provided in the "heading" (first few lines).

This "heading" information includes the bookmark file and the current [filtering type](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#FilteringIncrementallyByPatternMatching) (kinds of bookmarks that are shown). That is why more than one line is used. The bookmark file location alone can be wide, so it is placed on a line by itself.

There is no need for column headings, as it is pretty obvious that one is the bookmark name and the other is its location (e.g., file). And as there is no need for column headings, there is no need for an Emacs header line (which scrolls with the window, so that it is always visible, to let you know which column is which). The header line you show is pretty useless, IMHO, but even if you like it, you would need to do some programming to modify Bookmark+ to use it.

(As for the columns you show, I assume that you know that you can toggle showing the file column, using `M-t`.)

As for your two-character indentation: Bookmark+ uses the first 4 characters of each line for markers:

- First char: `D` or `>` (or ) for deletion flag or ordinary [mark](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#MarkingAndUnmarkingBookmarks) (or unmarked).
- Second char: `t` if the bookmark has [tags](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags) (or  if it has none).
- Third char: `X` or `a` (or ) for [temporary](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#TemporaryBookmarks) bookmark or [annotated](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkAnnotations) bookmark (or neither).
- Fourth char: `*` if the bookmark has unsaved modifications (or  otherwise).

So bookmark names are always "indented" 4 chars.